# Unable to open XLS file after converting file to Base64

Tags: java, base64

I need to send Email with xls attachment. In local i am geneating xls file. That file i am able to open with out any problem. But i am unable to open file in attachment. when i try to open displaying message like  "file format and extension of don't match" .

```
File fileBase = new File(FilePath);
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) fileBase.length()];
EmailAttachments emailAttachments = new EmailAttachments();
String base64 = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(bytes);
emailAttachments.setBase64(base64);
emailAttachments.setFileType("XLS");
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? The given code does not contain the value for `base64`. Have you manually checked what the sent mail contains?

Comment: String base64 = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(bytes);

Comment: Please add all clarification to the question itself, not to the comment section. Additionally, what have you tried to debug the problem?